# iOS and PHP: Check if server has updates/ database has changes

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

**Background**

I have an iOS app that retrieves data from a server and writes it to a file with NSFileManager, so that the user does not have to retrieve data again from the server every time they want to visit a page.  The data that they are retrieving can change from time to time, so I would like to update the data in the app files when it does.

I am using php pages for my backend web services.

**Question**

What is the technique for checking if the data in my database has changed so that I know that I should update the data in the app?  The only way I can think to do this is to create a php page that checks if the data is different from what I have stored, but this kind of defeats the purpose of saving information to files within the app.  I want to minimize when the user communicates with the server, because in situations where the user has no service, I would still like there to be valid data that they can see within the app.

Please ask questions if you do not fully understand what I am trying to achieve.  Thank you!

Comment: The right answer depends a lot on the kind of data you're talking about. Can you tell us more about them? Is it computed data or just static data stored in the database?

Comment: The data is just static in the database (list of restaurants, events, string descriptions, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list the most recently added restaurants for example, you could :

- Store the ID of the most recent restaurant on IOS and send it to the server when you want to check for updates.

  - If the ID isn't the same in the DB, then you have to update your client.
  - If it's the same, you can just send a response with a 304 status (Not modified) so you minimise the amount of data being exchange.

If you want to cache computed data, like top 10 user-rated restaurants, you can :

- Store a hash of the 10 restaurant IDs and send it to server when you want to check for updates.
- The server redo the request and compute the current hash for the top 10.

  - If the hash is different, update your client
  - If the hash is the same, send a response with a 304 status

**NB :** If the computation is expensive on server side, you might want to think about a more clever way to detect data changes.

Comment: I ended up creating a table in the database with version numbers for each table.  I update the version numbers in that table when I update data in the corresponding table.  I store those values in NSUserDefaults and check if the version has changed when the app launches.  Sound like a good plan?

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the cache is cleared on the app even if the data didn't actually changed. Example : you update a very old restaurant so the version number of the table change but the 10 most recently added restaurant have not changed... Yet all your apps will request the new list of recent restaurants.

Comment: I don't understand why that is a problem.  If I add one new restaurant to the restaurant table, I will get an entirely new list of restaurants (including the ones that already existed).  I just delete the file with the old list and create a new file with the updated list of restaurants.  Ideally, I would only update the one restaurant that changed but this method I'm using isn't just terrible is it?

Comment: The max number of any list I'm getting is only about 25 or 30 records

Comment: There is no problem with the case you describe. But you said you wanted to minimize the bandwidth used by your IOS app and your solution is not very efficient as you will invalid caches that are still valids.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to define your release ID on server and store somewhere in app as well. For example, when you do some changes in database or there is an update from server side. Just change that release ID from server.

On IOS side you need to check that release ID. If ios release id is lower than server's ID, then update your database in ios local storage.

Comment: That makes sense.  I understand how I would do this on the iOS side, but how/ where would I store a release ID on the server side.  Within the database or within the php pages, or somewhere else?

Comment: You can create constant variable in `PHP`. And make a separate web-service for that to check release ID. And you can update that constant variable whenever you need from PHP. OR If you don't want to change code every time then you can also add in in database and update it from your `php` application.